# Recover Time Machine partition that turned MBR only instead of GUID

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, time-machine

I have one drive that has a NTFS partition, a TimeMachine partition (I guess HFS+) and empty space. The other day, I did one partition more from Windows 8 (bootcamp) and since then, I can't see the TimeMachine one from OSX, I can see it from Windows though.

The problem is that TimeMachine uses a file system that Windows cannot browse, only shows some folders and I need to recover this partition because I have to use it to backup my Mac.

On OSX I can only see the NTFS partition and the other one appears unmounted and it's impossible to mount. I've come to the conclusion that something has happened to the partition table.

With TestDisk it shows that it's MBR only when I think it should be GUID:

[image: Pic1]

And pressing <kbd>p</kbd> shows that it's FDisk_partition_scheme and the TimeMachine one appears as Windows_NTFS.

[image: Pic2]

I found this thread that is similar to what it's happening to me: 
[Adding NTFS partition to disk in Windows makes HFS+ partition on same disk invisible in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/342876/adding-ntfs-partition-to-disk-in-windows-makes-hfs-partition-on-same-disk-invis)

Answer (score 0):

First, backup the MBR before trying anything. Better to have something half-woking than nothing at all.

Then, I'm not an OS X user therefore I don't know much about it. But here are some hints : with the help of gdisk, and if you are sure it should be a GPT, you can convert it. Start `gdisk <path_to_your_disk>`, it should warn you about the conversion. Another time, do that after having made a backup of the MBR. Then type `w` to write the new GPT. Type `p` to list the partition of the disk. Use `t` to change the type of a partition. NTFS should be `0700` and HFS+ `af00`. Type `l` to list available partition type. Type `w` again, then `q` to quit. Reboot, or unplug/plug your disk if you can in order to reload the partition table.

Another thing : the Disk Utility from OS X may give you some information about the drive state. It also provides some rescue utilities if I'm right. This may also help.